# Dynamic Theming and Polymer 2

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, themes, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to dynamically theme with polymer 2

I want to be able to load an external html file containing the theme, eg

```
<custom-style>
<style>
/* my theme setup */
</style>
</custom-style>
```

I've put a repo together giving an outline of what I've attempted.

https://github.com/moodyjmz/ang4-p2-theming

So far I've got a slightly hacky solution injecting the import-href in so that it is picked up with shadyCSS. This approach, whilst feeling wrong, works fine x browser, but conflicts with angular 4 polyfills. I can resolve this by modifying the final build index.html to only load angular after the web components polyfill is ready.

However, I would prefer to not do this and have a solution that relies on a less hacky approach

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.updateStyles({
  '--app-foo-style': red,
  '--app-bar-style': `12px`,
});
```

Comment: whilst this would work for simple use cases, I want to dynamically apply it across hundreds if not thousands of css rules and elements within angular, other elements and in slots.

Comment: Currently I'm veering toward a webpack build, maintaining a list of elements I care about and iterating that using `ShadyCSS.styleSubtree(el)`.

eg
On the element

```js
...
      ready () {
        super.ready();
        window.elList ? window.elList.push(this) : window.elList = [this];
      }
...
```
On the theme switcher - when a theme is detected and loaded via importHref - the callback would do:

```js
          if (window.elList) {
            window.elList.forEach(function (el) {
              ShadyCSS.styleSubtree(el);
            });
          }
```